# Is there a good website to share and optimize code together?

Tags: android, ios

Recently I am working on Android app development, and also I did iOS app before. I am not good at Android so far, so sometimes I found the app is kind lagging, thought [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) is very nice place to share and found the bug, but I would like to ask if there are some websites that I can share all codes and details about the app, and there are also some programmers there they can read and point it out what's wrong with my app? I don't know if this question is legal here, just think it's good to have one and learn more..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can post code and get it reviewed at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would probably be to push your projects to a site like [Github](https://github.com/) where there's a great infrastructure in place to allow people to collaborate with you.

Asking people to do so is a different issue, but probably best achieved through posts on XDA-developers and equivalent forums.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of places where you can post your entire source code. Here are two that I have used:

- Google Code: allows you to post your code publicly with details about downloading. You can use this and google forumns to get reviewed and help. SVN access is easy to configure. Can add others to projects.
- SourceForge: allows you to post code publicly and privately. SVN is easy once again. Allows you to add others users to the project with read/write/edit permissions.

Those two may not be the best places for getting reviewed and help easily, but they are wonderful for hosting and source control!

Also, these do have forumns where you can point others to your projects and ask questions!